# BizTalk error: failed while updating the application "BizTalk.System"

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, biztalk-deployment

I'm using biztalk 2009 and trying to deploy via vs.net 2008.

My project is just an empty BizTalk application with an empty orchestration.  I've created a strong name key file and selected it in the Project properties under "Signing".  I've also specified an application name.

When I deploy I get the error:
Error 1 Failed while Updating the Application 'BizTalk.System'. Permission denied. The current user does not have privilege to complete the operation.  0 0

Any ideas on what this means and what I'm doing wrong?  From what I know it's not supposed to be updating BizTalk.System at all.

Answer (score 2):

The BizTalk.System application is read-only so it can't be updated, but I doubt that you would be trying to update it without knowing it, especially with such a simple sounding project.  Your new application should be referencing BizTalk.System though... maybe there is a problem creating this dependency?

These are some of the initial steps I would take to troubleshoot:

- Check the BizTalkMgmtDb database to make sure you have the appropriate permissions
- Check the EventViewer logs for more details about the Access Denied error
- Try creating an empty application manually in the BizTalk Admin Console, see if you get the same error
- If you can create the application manually, try deploying the project via VS 2008 to the empty application and see if you get the same error

Hopefully one of these will help pinpoint what the problem is (or even better, hopefully you've alreadty resolved the issue :) )

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you shouldn't be deploying to the BizTalk.System application.

To check that you are deploying to the correct place, open your BizTalk project properties and click on the 'Deployment' tab (I'm making the assumption above that you are deploying *locally*, in which case the BizTalk Group *Server* and *Configuration Database* should already be set).

Under BizTalk Group, set *Application Name* to 'Test Application' (this can be changed later to something more meaningful); ensure all of the other boolean properties on the Deployment tab are set to true, with the exception of the *Enable Unit Testing* property.

When you now deploy the project from Visual Studio (by right clicking the project name and selecting 'Deploy', the new BizTalk Application will be created and the project deployed as a resource to that Application. Watch the VS Output window to check that they deployment is successful.

Once the deployment has completed, open the BizTalk Server Administration Console and expand the Applications node, you should now see a new application called 'Test Application'. If you expand the new app and take a look in *Resources*, you will see your recently deployed project.